# error APT2260 resource font not found in Xamarin.Android project

Tags: xamarin, fonts, xamarin.android

I am trying to find a replacement for Calligraphy now that I must upgrade my project to API Level 29.  I didn't have any luck with a new port so I am trying the native solution as suggested below:

https://medium.com/@davidmigloz/migrating-custom-fonts-from-calligraphy-to-android-fonts-3b635fd945dc

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml?authuser=1

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/

https://johnthiriet.com/xamarin-android-custom-font/

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

*error APT2260: resource font/IndieFlower (aka com.________) not found.*

I followed the instructions about moving the fonts from Assets to the Resources/font folder, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the font name has to be all lowercase!  It didn't have to be this way when the files were in the Assets folder, but apparently when they are in Resource/font they must.